# SwiftUI: Binding to @AppStorage

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, userdefaults

In the following example how can I change the value of `activeSheet` based on how SwiftUI updates `aArrived` and `bArrived`?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @AppStorage("didAArrive") var aArrived: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("didBArrive") var bArrived: Bool = false

    enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case aArrived, bArrived

        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }

    @State private var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .sheet(
                item: $activeSheet,
                content: { item in
                    switch item {
                    case .aArrived:
                        Text("A arrived")
                    case .bArrived:
                        Text("B arrived")
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `whatArrived` ever change independently of `aArrived` or `bArrived`? If not, don't make it a `@State` variable, just make it a computed property.

Comment: I need it as the item argument for the sheet(item:) modifier so I think I need it to be State.

Comment: That just means that it needs to be a Binding. It would help to update the question with the requirements. Otherwise, it sounds like you already know how to use onAppear and onChange.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom binding for the sheet which gets its value based on `aArrived` and `bArrived`. The binding value will be initialised based on `aArrived` or `bArrived` and get updated every time that either one changes.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @AppStorage("didAArrive") var aArrived: Bool = false
    @AppStorage("didBArrive") var bArrived: Bool = false

    enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case aArrived, bArrived

        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        let sheetBinding = Binding<ActiveSheet?>(
            get: {
                if aArrived && bArrived {
                    return ActiveSheet.aArrived
                } else if aArrived {
                    return ActiveSheet.aArrived
                } else if bArrived {
                    return ActiveSheet.bArrived
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            },
            set: { _ in }
        )
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Toggle("A arrived", isOn: $aArrived)
            Toggle("B arrived", isOn: $bArrived)
        }
        .sheet(
            item: sheetBinding,
            content: { item in
                switch item {
                case .aArrived:
                    Text("A arrived")
                case .bArrived:
                    Text("B arrived")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```